# I've got my 2D/3D conversion working perfectly, how to do perspective

Tags: math, 3d, 2d, coordinates, perspective

Although the context of this question is about making a 2d/3d game, the problem i have boils down to some math.
Although its a 2.5D world, lets pretend its just 2d for this question.

```
// xa: x-accent, the x coordinate of the projection
// mapP: a coordinate on a map which need to be projected
// _Dist_ values are constants for the projection, choosing them correctly will result in i.e. an isometric projection 
xa = mapP.x * xDistX + mapP.y * xDistY; 
ya = mapP.x * yDistX + mapP.y * yDistY;
```

xDistX and yDistX determine the angle of the x-axis, and xDistY and yDistY determine the angle of the y-axis on the projection (and also the size of the grid, but lets assume this is 1-pixel for simplicity).

```
x-axis-angle = atan(yDistX/xDistX)
y-axis-angle = atan(yDistY/yDistY)
```

a "normal" coordinate system like this

```
--------------- x
|
|
|
|
|
y

has values like this:
xDistX = 1;
yDistX = 0;
xDistY = 0;
YDistY = 1;
```

So every step in x direction will result on the projection to 1 pixel to the right end 0 pixels down. Every step in the y direction of the projection will result in 0 steps to the right and 1 pixel down.
When choosing the correct xDistX, yDistX, xDistY, yDistY, you can project any trimetric or dimetric system (which is why i chose this).

So far so good, when this is drawn everything turns out okay. If "my system" and mindset are clear, lets move on to perspective.
I wanted to add some perspective to this grid so i added some extra's like this:

```
camera = new MapPoint(60, 60);
dx = mapP.x - camera.x; // delta x
dy = mapP.y - camera.y; // delta y
dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); // dist is the distance to the camera, Pythagoras etc.. all objects must be in front of the camera

fac = 1 - dist / 100; // this formula determines the amount of perspective

xa = fac * (mapP.x * xDistX  + mapP.y * xDistY) ;
ya = fac * (mapP.x * yDistX + mapP.y * yDistY );
```

Now the real hard part... what if you got a (xa,ya) point on the projection and want to calculate the original point (x,y).
For the first case (without perspective) i did find the inverse function, but how can this be done for the formula with the perspective. May math skills are not quite up to the challenge to solve this.

( I vaguely remember from a long time ago mathematica could create inverse function for some special cases... could it solve this problem? Could someone maybe try?)

Comment: What is `fac`? What is the "amount of perspective"? What does 100 have to do with anything? Is `fac` meant to implement the apparent shrinking of objects due to perspective. This makes object at distance 100 have size zero, so that doesn't make sense?

Comment: fac stands for factor, like in a perspective factor which can be adjusted for heavy or little perspective. Drawing the grid using this function gave something which did look good enough. Objects should always be placed on "the grid" an in front of the camera. This means an object can never have a distance greater then sqrt(60^2+60^2) 85. The reason i choose 100 is because its bigger then 85, and gave me the look i needed.
My function is not correct, but the visual result sort of looked good, although the "perspective" is a bit overdone... 
http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/5154/gridpu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you've defined doesn't have an inverse. Just as an example, as user207422 already pointed out anything that's 100 units away from the camera will get mapped to (xa,ya)=(0,0), so the inverse isn't uniquely defined.

More importantly, that's not how you calculate perspective. Generally the perspective scaling factor is defined to be `viewdist/zdist` where `zdist` is the perpendicular distance from the camera to the object and `viewdist` is a constant which is the distance from the camera to the hypothetical screen onto which everything is being projected. (See the diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_transform#Diagram), but feel free to ignore everything else on that page.) The scaling factor you're using in your example doesn't have the same behaviour.

Here's a stab at trying to convert your code into a correct perspective calculation (note I'm not simplifying to 2D; perspective is about projecting three dimensions to two, trying to simplify the problem to 2D is kind of pointless):

```
camera = new MapPoint(60, 60, 10);
camera_z = camera.x*zDistX + camera.y*zDistY + camera.z*zDistz;

// viewdist is the distance from the viewer's eye to the screen in
// "world units". You'll have to fiddle with this, probably.
viewdist = 10.0;

xa = mapP.x*xDistX + mapP.y*xDistY + mapP.z*xDistZ;
ya = mapP.x*yDistX + mapP.y*yDistY + mapP.z*yDistZ;
za = mapP.x*zDistX + mapP.y*zDistY + mapP.z*zDistZ;

zdist = camera_z - za;
scaling_factor = viewdist / zdist;
xa *= scaling_factor;
ya *= scaling_factor;
```

You're only going to return `xa` and `ya` from this function; `za` is just for the perspective calculation. I'm assuming the the "za-direction" points out of the screen, so if the pre-projection x-axis points towards the viewer then `zDistX` should be positive and vice-versa, and similarly for `zDistY`. For a trimetric projection you would probably have `xDistZ==0`, `yDistZ<0`, and `zDistZ==0`. This would make the pre-projection z-axis point straight up post-projection.

Now the bad news: this function doesn't have an inverse either. Any point (xa,ya) is the image of an infinite number of points (x,y,z). But! If you assume that z=0, then you can solve for x and y, which is possibly good enough.

To do that you'll have to do some linear algebra. Compute `camera_x` and `camera_y` similar to `camera_z`. That's the post-transformation coordinates of the camera. The point on the screen has post-tranformation coordinates `(xa,ya,camera_z-viewdist)`. Draw a line through those two points, and calculate where in intersects the plane spanned by the vectors `(xDistX, yDistX, zDistX)` and `(xDistY, yDistY, zDistY)`. In other words, you need to solve the equations:

```
x*xDistX + y*xDistY == s*camera_x + (1-s)*xa
x*yDistX + y*yDistY == s*camera_y + (1-s)*ya
x*zDistX + y*zDistY == s*camera_z + (1-s)*(camera_z - viewdist)
```

It's not pretty, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that with your post i can solve the problem. Still, to clarify some questions:

Solving the problem in 2d is useless indeed, but this was only done to make the problem easier to grasp (for me and for the readers here). My program actually give's a perfect 3d projection (i checked it with 3d images rendered with blender). I did left something out about the inverse function though. The inverse function is only for coordinates between 0..camera.x * 0.5 and 0.. camera.y*0.5. So in my example between 0 and 30. But even then i have doubt's about my function.

In my projection the z-axis is always straight up, so to calculate the height of an object i only used the vieuwingangle. But since you cant actually fly or jumpt into the sky everything has only a 2d point. This also means that when you try to solve the x and y, the z really is 0.

I know not every funcion has an inverse, and some functions do, but only for a particular domain. My basic thought in this all was... if i can draw a grid using a function... every point on that grid maps to exactly one map-point. I can read the x and y coordinate so if i just had the correct function i would be able to calculate the inverse. 
But there is no better replacement then some good solid math, and im very glad you took the time to give a very helpfull responce :).

Comment: Just for future reference, this normally would have gone in an edit to your question, or perhaps in comments.